# Convergence of integral: $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}}{x^{a}}\ dx $

Tags: absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

I need to determine about convergence of integral below.I found out that it doesn't converge absolutely but i have problem with determining about conditional convergence.I am not sure how to use Dirichlet test in this case.I would be grateful for any advice.Please don't use taylor expansion or similar techniques.

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}}{x^{a}}\ dx $$

Comment: What are your parameters on $a$? For $a>1$,  you're integral is absolutely convergent, so presumably you're talking about $a \leq 1$. But is $a>0$, for instance?

Comment: $a$ belongs to real numbers and i should determine for what parameter $a$ it converges ...

Comment: and i am sure that it doesn't converge absolutely for any $a$ bacause of limit test...

Comment: Whoops. I saw it converges at the upper bound, and forgot the lower bound was also trouble. But it is good to know that your need to determine for which real $a$ it converges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By splitting $\mathbb{R}^+$ as $(0,1]\cup(1,+\infty)$ and performing the substitution $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$ on the second "half" we have that

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^a}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\sin\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^{a-1}}+\frac{\sin\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^{1-a}}\right)\,\frac{dx}{x} $$
and the RHS can be written (via $x+\frac{1}{x}\mapsto 2z$) as
$$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(2z)}{\sqrt{z^2-1}}\left[\left(z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)^{a-1}+\left(z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)^{1-a}\right]\,dz. \tag{A}$$
For any $a\in(0,2)$ the function
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2-1}}\left[\left(z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)^{a-1}+\left(z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)^{1-a}\right] $$
is decreasing to zero from some point on, hence the integral is convergent by Dirichlet's test ($\sin(2z)$ has a bounded primitive). If $a<0$ or $a>2$ the $(A)$-integral is blatantly divergent, so you only have to study the case $a=0$ (which is equivalent to the case $a=2$). It leads to the outcome $-\pi Y_1(2)$, where $Y$ is a [Bessel function of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_second_kind:_Y%CE%B1). The substitution $z=\cosh\theta$ immediately allows to recognize the relation between your integral and the Laplace transform of $\sin(2\cosh\theta)$.